# Passing Values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In the code I am posting, I am using a check box called "ACDS Test" and whenever it is checked it creates a sheet, then when it becomes unchecked it calls the upper function and deletes the sheet.

I am trying to add a message box that essentially works like a fail safe to ensure they want to delete the page. If they say they do not want to delete the page then I want the checkbox to stay checked.

For some reason I am getting this error message when I try to pass the value to make sure the checkbox stays checked and I cannot figure out why.

The error comes up on the line:
Sub ACDSTest_Click(CorrectValue As Integer)
And the specific error is: "Compile error: Procedure Declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name".

Any help is much appreciated! IF any more clarification is needed please feel free to ask!

```
Sub DeleteWorksheet(NameSheet As String)

    Dim Ans As Long
    Dim t As String
    Dim CorrectValue As Integer
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    k = Sheets.Count


    Ans = MsgBox("Would you like to take this test off of the form?", vbYesNo)
    Select Case Ans
        Case vbYes
            'Code reads through each page and finds one with corresponding name to string t
            'Once it finds the correct page, it deletes it
            For i = k To 1 Step -1
                t = Sheets(i).Name
                If t = NameSheet Then
                    Sheets(i).Delete
                End If
            Next i
            CorrectValue = 0
        Case vbNo
            CorrectValue = 1
    End Select

End Sub

Sub ACDSTest_Click(CorrectValue As Integer)

    Dim NameSheet As String
    Dim NameValue As String
    NameSheet = "ACDS"
    NameValue = "ACDS Test"

    If ACDSTest.Value = True Then
        CreateWorksheet (NameSheet), (NameValue)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Else
        DeleteWorksheet (NameSheet)
        If CorrectValue = 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("ACDS Test").ControlFormat.Value = 1
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message and on which line?

Comment: The error comes up on the line Sub ACDSTest_Click(CorrectValue As Integer)

Comment: The specific error is "Compile Error: Procedure Declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Comment: You also don't need tests like  If ACDSTest.Value = True   as you can simply say If ACDSTest.Value  (potentially even just  If ACDSTest (depending on the default property)

Comment: You can't just add a parameter to the event code. You don't even need it. Remove `(CorrectValue As Integer)` as it's redundant.

Comment: Please [edit] that info into your question and also indicate which line this occurs on.

Comment: Actually I see you do use it, however you are not passing the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `CorrectValue` variable as you define it in `DeleteWorksheet` does not exist in the context of the 
variable does not exist in context of the `ACDSTest_Click` subroutine. This is because variables defined within subroutines or functions are local to those functions. To correct this I would convert `DeleteWorksheet` to a function such as the below.

Further, the event that fires `Private Sub ACDSTest_Click()` cannot handle passing a value to that function, so changing it to `Sub ACDSTest_Click(CorrectValue As Integer)` causes an error.

```vb
Function DeleteWorksheet(ByVal SheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo SheetDNE
        SheetName = Sheets(SheetName).Name 'Check if sheet exists w/o other objects
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case MsgBox("Would you like to take this test off of the form?", vbYesNo)
        Case vbYes
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(SheetName).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            DeleteWorksheet = True
        Case Else: DeleteWorksheet = False
    End Select
    Exit Function 'Exit The Function w/o error
SheetDNE:   'Sheet Does Not Exist
    MsgBox "The indicated sheet, " & SheetName & ", does not exist", vbOKOnly
End Function
```

And

```vb
Private Sub ACDSTest_Click()

    Dim NameSheet As String
    Dim NameValue As String
    NameSheet = "ACDS"
    NameValue = "ACDS Test"

    If ACDSTest.Value = True Then
        CreateWorksheet (NameSheet), (NameValue)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Else 
        If Not DeleteWorksheet(NameSheet) Then _ 
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("ACDS Test").ControlFormat.Value = 1
    End If

End Sub
```